# Confused about the definition of a function. "Each a in A belongs to a unique ordered pair, (a,b) in f". What about asymptotes?

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory

Studying Set theory, specifically functions. My textbook says as follows:

> A function $f:A\rightarrow B$ is a relation from $A$ to $B$ (i.e, a subset of $A\times B$) such that each $a$ in $A$ belongs to a unique ordered pair, $(a,b)$ in $f$.

This seems to add an additional 'rule' to the definition of a function from what I am familiar with in calculus. The requirement that *every* $a$ must map to some b is confusing to me. What about functions with vertical asymptotes? Don't those functions map from $\mathbb R\rightarrow\mathbb R$, but there is some a value where the function is not defined? Or the same could be said about functions with "holes".

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: If there's a member of $\mathbb R$ where the function is not defined, then it is **not** a function from $\mathbb R$ to $\mathbb R$.  It is a function from some subset of $\mathbb R$ to $\mathbb R$.

Comment: The fact that a relation is from R to R and can be represented in the cartesian plane implies (1) neither that this relation is a function from R to R, (2) nor even that this relation is a function. For example, the selation defined by { (x,y) | x and y are real numbers and x²+y²=1} is a relation from R to R, but not a function from R to R, since it is not even a function.

Answer (score 12):

In situations like vertical asymptotes and holes, the domain is adjusted to avoid those points.

For instance, the function $f(x) = \frac{1}{x}$ does *not* have domain $\mathbb{R}$.  It has domain $\{x \in \mathbb{R}: x \neq 0\}$.

Comment: Which I think is sometimes written as $\mathbb R / 0 $ for short?

Comment: I think you mean $\mathbb{R}\setminus\{0\}$